# Is it possible to do a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION ..) in ZoHo reports?

Tags: sql, zoho

I'm trying to do the following, in Zoho .. but I can't figure out how to do `ROW_COUNT()`, `OVER` and `PARTITION(..)`..

```
User  | Class | Age
Foo   | "A"   | 10
Bah   | "A"   | 12
Fred  | "B"   | 11
Jane  | "A"   | 11
```

and I'm after the eldest child, in each class.

Results

```
Class "A": Bah (12 years old)
Class "B": Fred (11 years old).
```

This can be done quite simply with a `ROW_NUMBER, OVER PARTITION`

Can this be done in ZOHO?

Comment: Did you find an answer?